# File not found in script

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, node-modules

I've installed several libraries using NPM.
You have to load the file to use it there.All installed libraries are under the node_modules

The designation is like this.

```
<script src="../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

I'm sure it's on the server, I'm sure the URL of the script tag is correct
And I get the following error in the script, even though it is specified like this

> login.html:45 GET https://***/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

The JS file I prepared separately is loaded, but the original vue.js is not, so an error is coming back.

That's what we're trying to do with VUE.
I'm going to use Ajax to create an SPA

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
const vue = require("vue"); //I added it, but it's still not working.
const axios = require("axios"); //I added it, but it's still not working.
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
data: {
    url: "https://*****",
    user: "",
    password: "",
    res: ""
},
methods: {
    login: function () {
        axios.post(this.url, {
            user: this.user,
            password: this.password
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                this.res = response.data.d;
                if (this.res === true) {
                    //true
                } else {
                    //failed
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                alert('System error');
            });
    }
}
```

})

Comment: Which server framework are you using? Express?

Comment: @mepley No, it's a windows server.

Comment: Capitalize the "v" in `Vue` where you are requiring it and see if this works. For example: `const Vue = require("vue");`

Comment: @mepley If I rewrite it like that and still can't use Vue, do I know what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how usually use it from `node_module`

```
import Vue from 'vue'; // this will check inside node_modules for the file and include
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading the files through a script tag, use `require()` in your javascript. For example:

```
const express = require("express");
const vue = require("vue");
```

This will work on both the client and on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a CDN?

This way, the browser will not have to download the Vue file from your server if it has already been cached. Also, you may be able to use the vue.min.js file which will load even faster than the normal Vue dist file...

For example, here is a script from cdnjs.com you could try:

```
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js" 
  integrity="sha256-ngFW3UnAN0Tnm76mDuu7uUtYEcG3G5H1+zioJw3t+68=" 
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Try replacing your script tag with this.

Comment: The reason for not using a CDN is that the download hassle is the biggest impact.
And because it is easier to share the environment with others when using NPM

Comment: Can you explain further why you are trying to directly import the vue.js code directly from the node_modules folder? Why not just require it as suggested by @greyson-r? Also, what do you mean that the "download hassle is the biggest impact"?

Comment: I don't know how to import files prepared by npm install, so I'm using script tag to try
Downloading is because I thought it would be faster to download on the same server because the net speed does not come out much.

Comment: Did you try what @greyson-r suggested? That is the proper way to import javascript into another javascript file. I'm surprised that you are trying to use npm but somehow have not learned how to import/require modules. Here is some info about this: https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm-packages-in-your-projects

Comment: I've tried it, but it's not working.
I thought it was something you could install with npm but import with a script tag
Thank you, that's very helpful.

Comment: What are you trying to do with Vue? Can you edit your question with some of your code that might help us understand what you are trying to accomplish?